# How do I start WebXR from an iframe within Next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js, iframe, webxr, model-viewer

I have a Next.js app

- https://codesandbox.io/s/next-js-forked-6fgnr7?file=/index.tsx

and it **should open WebXR** on Android Chrome **when I click on the AR button bottom left** ("in AR betrachten"). But it falls back to the Android Scene Viewer.

The iframe source is https://polygoningenieur.dev/.
If I go to https://polygoningenieur.dev/ directly in my browser, it works, WebXR is opening.

[image: Screenshots from Scene Viewer and WebXR]

The Sandbox is a standard next.js app, the next.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Permissions-Policy",
            value: "xr-spatial-tracking=()"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
  }
};
```

and the index.tsx like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <div id="ar-layout">
      <iframe
        src="https://polygoningenieur.dev"
        id="ar-showcase"
        title="AR-App Example"
        width="800"
        height="600"
        allow="xr-spatial-tracking"
        allowFullScreen
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

So I am not sure what I am missing here. The AR app is on a https domain, the iframe has allow="xr-spatial-tracking" and I have set the permission policy header to allow xr-spatial-tracking in the next.config.js.
(Codesandbox says allow on iframe is a unknown prop, but there is no complaint about that in my local environment.)

*(Additional info: I am using Chrome on Android, the AR-App is built with model viewer and is static with html and JavaScript.)*

But why is it not working? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they are using [model viewer](https://modelviewer.dev/examples/augmentedreality/) to showcase 3d models in AR.
You can also use the same in your nextjs app using this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google/model-viewer)

Demo codesandbox link :
https://codesandbox.io/s/google-model-viewer-nextjs-p4gge

Demo glitch link :
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/grave-verbose-angora?path=index.html%3A19%3A17

To try 3d models into  modelviewer you can use glb file file from following:

1. [Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/store/3d-models?pbr=1&ref=header)
2. [Turbosquid](https://www.turbosquid.com/)
3. [CGtrader](https://www.cgtrader.com/)
4. [3dexport](https://3dexport.com/) etc.

Comment: this is my project, so I already use model viewer with a 3d model and everything is fine... except my issue described above